# hide keyboard on ios device when focus in input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want hide virtual keyboard on ipad device when some plugin ( or other code) set focus to input element on html page using pure javascript( or jquery library)

Comment: What do you expect to happen after you set focus on the input element?  If there's no keyboard, why focus it in the first place?

Comment: Why would you want to focus on an input yet not show the keyboard?

Comment: ok, how to be in next situation. I have a popup window with 3 inputs. When I clik on submit button runs validation function from validation plugin ([link]https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine) and virtual keyboard is blinking on page, after that all works fine.

Comment: Why would you not want to focus on the input? Answer: Programmatic entry.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you need a pure [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) solution, use this line :

```
document.activeElement.blur();
```

This line removes the focus on the **active element** and hiding the keyboard.

---

*Reference*

- [MDN document.activeElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.activeElement)
- [MDN HTMLElement.blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.blur)

Comment: This worked perfectly to remove the on-screen keyboard on mobile. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You would have to blur it again but the keyboard might flash.

```
$('input').on('focus', function() { $(this).blur(); });
```

Or, depending on if you have dynamically created `input` elements.

```
$('#wrapper').on('focus', 'input', function() { $(this).blur(); });
```

Comment: This will be the best approach in my opinion. +1

Comment: how to be in next situation. I have a popup window with 3 inputs. When I clik on submit button runs validation function from validation plugin ([link]github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine) and virtual keyboard is blinking on page, after that all works fine.

Comment: why don't you hook up validation for all fields on blur rather than on click of a validate button?

Answer (score 1):

Typescript version requires to fire `blur()` on `HTMLElement`. Like this:

```
let myElement: HTMLElement;
myElement = <HTMLElement>document.activeElement;
myElement.blur()
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, it needs waiting for a while.

```
setTimeout(function() { document.activeElement.blur(); }, 100);
```